# Unexpected token , ES6 array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have the following code.
It is an array but it throws the error:

> ```
> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,
> ```

```
var counting = {4, 2, 14}.map((x) => {
    var add = x + 1;
    return x * add;
});
console.log(counting);
```

Comment: to make an array, use square brackets, not curly brackets.

Comment: user array notation

Comment: downvoting does it mean you are smart people here, he is posting 1st question please help them in the right direction.

Comment: @HD.. This isn't OP's first post... Though I agree it is not worth downvoting

Comment: yes he is not, but we should help them in right path

Comment: @HD..As always, upvote a good question

Comment: I recommend reading http://eloquentjavascript.net/04_data.html .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You confuse `[]` array construction with `{}` object construction .

```js
var counting = [4, 2, 14].map((x) => {
    return x * (x + 1);
});
console.log(counting);
```

I have removed the extra line of code that simply added one to `x`. This makes the code easier to read and maintain.

Answer (score 2):

[Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) literal notation uses `[]` not `{}`.